# WPF with LiveCharts add series with DataBinding at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, livecharts

I have a project where I have a charting area.
I have choosen LiveCharts ( http://lvcharts.net ) for that matter.

So far so good, the charting works with databinding when added in xaml:
[image]

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Work_Task_Planner_Sheduler.Views.TeamTaskProgressChartView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Work_Task_Planner_Sheduler.Views"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="TeamTaskProgressChartComponent">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                <lvc:LineSeries Title="Julian" Values="{Binding Taskprogress_julian}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Time"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="TaskProgress"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The issue is: The Line series is hardcoded in xaml. Who knows if the team gets bigger/smaller over time or the team members change. Therefore I want to create the line series at runtime.

This is what I have so far, unfortunately the series stays empty:

```cs
CartesianChart chart = this.TeamTaskProgressChartComponent;
foreach(string user in TeamMembers)
{
    LineSeries lineseries = new LineSeries();
    string title = user.Split('.')[0];
    lineseries.Title = title;
    Binding databinding = new Binding();
    databinding.Source =
    Datarefresh.mainWindow.mainViewModel.TeamTaskProgressChartViewModel.TaskProgressCounts;
    DependencyProperty LineSeriesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(title+"Property", typeof(int), typeof(LineSeries), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    lineseries.SetBinding(LineSeriesProperty, databinding);
    chart.series.Add(lineseries);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Process is quite Simple:

1. Create a Series collation. IMPORTANT: The series collection must be initialized in the constructor so that it is ready when the chart loads:

   ```cs
   public class TeamTicketResolveChartViewModel
   {
       public SeriesCollection ChartSeries { get; set; }
       public string[] TicketResolveLabels { get; set; }

       public TeamTicketResolveChartViewModel()
       {
           ChartSeries = new SeriesCollection();
           foreach (string user in TeamMembers.ServiceDesk)
           {
               LineSeries lineseries = new LineSeries();
               string title = user.Split('.')[0];
               lineseries.Title = title;
               ChartSeries.Add(lineseries);
           }
       }
       // other functions
   }
   ```
2. In xaml, bind the chart to the series Collection:

   ```xml
   <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="TeamTicketResolveChartComponent" Series="{Binding ChartSeries}" />
   ```
3. Now updating the Chart Data will work as intended:

   ```
   public void LoadChartData2(List<List<(DateTime time, int resolved)>> input)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
       {
           ChartSeries[i].Values = new ChartValues<int>(input[i].Select(c => c.resolved));
       }

       DateTime[] dates = input[0].Select(c => c.time).ToArray();
       List<string> labels = new List<string>();
       foreach (DateTime time in dates) labels.Add(time.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
       TicketResolveLabels = labels.ToArray();
   }
   public void AddChartPoint(List<List<(DateTime time, int resolved)>> input)
   {
       // Chartseries[i].values.Add()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the source for the binding.

```
CartesianChart chart = new CartesianChart();
foreach(string user in TeamMembers)
{
    LineSeries lineseries = new LineSeries();
    string title = user.Split('.')[0];
    lineseries.Title = title;
    Binding databinding = new Binding("Taskprogress_"+title);

    //===========Set source here before setting the binding to the lineseries===========
    databinding.Source = "your datasource";

    // the following line is pseudocode derived from Microsoft reference
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-      a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
    lineseries.SetBinding(LineSeries.Values, databinding); 
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code on top. I can now compile and run the application but the series stays empty. this works when defining the same in xaml